Google Earth Engine updateMask() with a mask of finer resolution gives strange results
It seems updateMask() will keep the projection of the original image. However, masking the original image with a finer resolution image produces strange results in the following calculation.
As the example below, I mask band8 (1000m resolution) with band1 (500m resolution) threshold (no clear physical meaning, just for simplicity), and then count the unmasked pixel of band8 in a small region using reduceRegion(). When doing reduceRegion() on 500m scale (original scale of band1), it gives 20, which is correct. However, when I do reduceRegion() on 1000m scale (the original scale of band8), it gives 3, which seems strange. I would expect it to be 5.
I was wondering what happened in the calculation. Can I use updateMask() with a finer resolution image? Will the original image be correctly weighted?
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-55.63880116609673, -1.1262068875826794],
          [-55.63880116609673, -1.1890221253423552],
          [-55.55331380037407, -1.1890221253423552],
          [-55.55331380037407, -1.1262068875826794]]], null, false);
Map.addLayer(geometry, {}, 'geometry', true, 0.5);

// MOD19A1 dataset https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MCD19A1_GRANULES
var test_image = ee.Image('MODIS/061/MCD19A1_GRANULES/MCD19A1_A2019152_h12v09_061_2023126163400_01');

var band1 = test_image.select('Sur_refl1');  // scale: ~500 m
var band8 = test_image.select('Sur_refl8');  // scale: ~1000 m

// Mask band8 use threshold of band1
var mask_B1 = band1.lt(0.03 * 10000);
var band8_masked = band8.updateMask(mask_B1);

// Count the pixels with 1000 m scale
var pixel_count = band8_masked.mask().reduceRegion(
            {reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
            geometry: geometry,
            crs: band8_masked.projection().crs(),
            scale: band8_masked.projection().nominalScale(),
            maxPixels: 1e10}
        );
        
// Count the pixels with 500 m scale
var pixel_count2 = band8_masked.mask().reduceRegion(
            {reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
            geometry: geometry,
            crs: band1.projection().crs(),
            scale: band1.projection().nominalScale(),
            maxPixels: 1e10}
        );

print('Number of unmasked pixels in 1000 m', pixel_count);
print('Number of unmasked pixels in 500 m', pixel_count2);

Map.addLayer(band8_masked, {palette: ['black', 'white'], min: 0, max: 0.05 * 10000}, 'Band8 masked');
Map.addLayer(band1, {palette: ['black', 'white'], min: 0, max: 0.05 * 10000}, 'Band1');
Map.addLayer(band8, {palette: ['black', 'white'], min: 0, max: 0.05 * 10000}, 'Band8');
Map.addLayer(band8_masked.mask(), {}, 'mask', false);
Map.centerObject(geometry);


